# How do you shut down an expect script in the presence of a complex shell interface?

Tags: expect

I am running `zsh` inside of `tmux` with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), and a basic expect script is exiting improperly:

```
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
expect  -regex ".*"
send "echo 'foo'\r"
expect -regex ".*foo.*\r"
send "^D"
expect eof
```

What happens is the `foo` is output and expected, the script exits... but the prompt exposed afterwards is broken until I press `CTRL-C` on the keyboard.  At that point, a `%` is printed and the next line appears:

```
❯ ./modified-autoexpect-recording.exp
spawn /bin/zsh
echo 'foo'
❯ echo 'foo'
foo
~/ < ... fancy stuff ... ❯  ^C%  # this was a manual CTRL-C event from a broken prompt
~/ < ... fancy stuff ... ❯       # this is working
```

A straight autoexpect result produces the same problem. One of the things I noticed is:

```
~/long/path/here ❯ ^C%              
~/lo/pa/here ❯ # after exiting the frozen prompt
```

---

An end to end AutoExpect example:

```
$: autoexpect
$: echo 'foo'
foo
$:[CTRL-D]
$: ./script.exp
$:[CTRL-C]%
$: # prompt works
```

Behavior remains constant across the following modifications:

```
# changes at beginning
set log_user 0
set stty sane

# changes at end
send -- '^D' # -> send -- \x04
```

It definitely has something to do with the custom prompt's path getting abbreviated.

I am happy to change my prompt system, but ideally expect just works w/ some mods.

---

I am reviewing Don's book (O'Reilly), so maybe the answer is there.  In the meantime, are there any tricks to have an expect program exit robustly?

Comment: Try `log_user 0` at the start of the expect script to stop it copying data it read from the child to the terminal you are in, as it may include some escape sequences.

Comment: The expect may have effectively done `$ stty -echo`. You can undo that with `$ stty sane`.

Comment: although both fixes did not work, that's probably what is happening, adding details.

Comment: I assume the `^D` was ineffective, and you're still expecting eof. Try `send \x04`

Comment: Also `expect  -regex ".*"` is extremely permissive. It is expecting to see zero or more of any characters. You might want to match your prompt more precisely `expect -re { $}`

Comment: Similarly `expect -regex ".*foo.*\r"` matches the "foo" in `echo 'foo'`, so the ^D is being send quite early.

Comment: @glennjackman I'll adjust the original `autoexpect` result from the `^D`

Comment: Your next step: run with internal tracing on. You have an infinite timeout, and the program is hanging, so there must be a pattern that is not matching. Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script. The output is quite verbose. Look for "does this pattern match this buffer, yes or no"

Comment: @glennjackman thank you for the coaching, have to find a time to try